# Pass a function by variable to another function to be bound as a jQuery click event

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to pass a function via a variable to be assigned as part of a click event, for instance:

```
function bindClick(func) {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        func();
        return false;
    });
}

function configureClick() {
    bindClick(function () { executeClick(message); });
}

function executeClick(message) {
    alert(message);
}
```

So `configureClick()` will run at some point, and then `#button.click()` needs to call the contents of `func`.

Whatever's happening, is doing so silently, no errors nor desired behavior.

*UPDATE*: I'm an idiot! The code above is working. My `executeClick` had a switch-case block which was being ignored as I was passing the incorrect key. Sorry for the trouble D:

Comment: Missing brackets around `"bananas!"`?

Comment: If it doesn't work but there are no errors, make sure you use `$(document).ready`.

Comment: sorry, I meant `alert('bananas!')`, that's just a placeholder for "do other stuff"

Comment: @pimvdb `configureClick()` is called by user action, way after `$(document).ready`

Comment: Does the element exist? It works just fine as it stands: http://jsfiddle.net/NJtn9/.

Comment: @pimvdb Interesting, I may have oversimplified for the sakes of asking the question. Also, I've updated my original question to add a parameter for `executeClick()`. But as your jsfiddle works, I obviously need to look a bit harder at my own code. The element does exist however, as putting other lines within the click handler execute.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a failing demo on http://jsfiddle.net? Maybe you're calling `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` or something that prevents the handler from executing.

Comment: Annoyingly, transferring my code to JSFiddle and stripping out all the non-relevant parts leaves working code >_<. But since I've made it, http://jsfiddle.net/SVumx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do too much passing of callback function. That' creating lots of closures, which is not needed in such a simple case.

```
function bindClick(func) {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        func();
        return false;
    });
}


function executeClick(message) {
    alert(message);
}

function configureClick(message){
    bindClick(function(){ executeClick(message) });
}

configureClick('Hello');
```

Comment: Apologies. I have oversimplied, `executeClick()` requires a parameter, I'll update my original question.